# errorE0282# type annotations needed & could not compile `sp-arithmetic`

Tags: substrate

I am following tutorial [Implementing the Contract Trait]. Added code snip to [parameter_types!] and to [imp trait runtime].

When I run [cargo check -p node-template-runtime] receive error:
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
error: could not compile `sp-arithmetic`
note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

I've had this error previously and it was due to nightly?

I am using windows not mac..

Comment: made changes to runtime_lib.rs and when I run cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 check receive following errors#E0277:
cannot multiply MILLICENTS to {integer}
cannot multiply CENTS to {integer}

Comment: I added code snip to `pub const` and run `cargo check -p node-template-runtime`.. I get same error mentioned in initial post above:
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
error: could not compile `sp-arithmetic`

I would like to know if its due to my own mistake or is this due to nightly?

Comment: Strange - when I run `cargo +nightly-2020-10-06` instead of `cargo check -p node-template-runtime` I receive a different error:                                                               
`cannot multiply MILLICENTS to {integer}`                                                                                
  `cannot multiply CENTS to {integer}`

Comment: I would need more information about the changes you made to be able to help at this point. It seems like you changed some types and it's now causing problems.

Answer (score 4):

Just to Add to @dundro answer. Go to the link he suggested:

https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/commit/5769470053ba48f364100ff106e32f1beea43127

and download the "rust-toolchain" file. Then place it in the "substrate-node-template" folder. Then try to build again using the command "cargo build --release".

In my case, it solved the E0282 error and gave me a new one E0463. Searching for a fix now

Answer (score 3):

I got the exactly same error, but then I just checked out master ( there is now a toolchain file since https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/commit/5769470053ba48f364100ff106e32f1beea43127)
and with nightly-2020-10-06 the build was successful.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Solved: I forgot to add nightly [cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 check -p node-template-runtime]..